# Getting metada (column information) from sharepoint

Tags: java, sdk, metadata, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph SDK for Java (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) to extract documents from the Sharepoint. 
Is there a possibility to extract also information about the documents, apart the "standard" ones that GraphServiceClient gives?

Meaning with GraphServiceClient I can get createdBy, description, lastModifiedDateTime, webUrl... and appart from that I am trying to extract information that can be additionally defined in Sharepoint - there is a possibility to make custom fields/columns for documents and set values for each document.

I want to extract that additional "metadata". How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the DriveItem has less information about the files on sharepoint.
Therefore, using the ListItem is getting everything that is defined for the document...

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.
                                  builder().
                                  authenticationProvider(authenticator).
                                  logger(new Slf4jGraphLogger(logger)).
                                  buildClient();

ListItem fileMetadata = 
           graphClient.
           drives(driveId).
           items(item.id).
           listItem().
           buildRequest().get();
```

And there the fileMetadata has "fields" where all the metadata, custom and usual is stored...

My test query for a single document is:

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/listItem
```

and

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/listItem/fields
```

The respond is the same as in previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add the **$expand** to your query.

```
items = client
  .users(mailbox)
  .drives(drive-id)
  .items(att.id)
  .buildRequest(Lists.newArrayList(new QueryOption("$expand","fields"))) 
  .get();
```

## Note:

**Not all custom metadata can be retrieved by the Graph API.**

Short:

```
/items?expand=fields
```

My actual test query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site id}/drives/{drive-id}/list/items?expand=fields
```

Response(MyTestMetadata1 is my test metadata):

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('site id')/drives('drive id')/list/items",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"c800e34f-6ee4-4d46-8a56-2811078509e7,2\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-10-25T04:20:05Z",
            "eTag": "\"c800e34f-6ee4-4d46-8a56-2811078509e7,2\"",
            "id": "4",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2018-10-25T04:20:07Z",
            "webUrl": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Shared%20Documents/CenterText.js",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "f5d39dec-1642-48b2-90ee-1da477f61a1c",
                    "displayName": "xxx"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "f5d39dec-1642-48b2-90ee-1da477f61a1c",
                    "displayName": "xxx"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "id": "3638238d-a591-4105-b6c7-a9251be75d93"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x0101007264AD3105D388488F4C729B0CC03CCF"
            },
            "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('site-id')/drives('drive-id')/list/items('4')/fields/$entity",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"c800e34f-6ee4-4d46-8a56-2811078509e7,2\"",
                "Modified": "2018-10-25T04:20:07Z",
                "FileLeafRef": "CenterText.js",
                "MyTestMetadata1": "OK",
                "id": "4",
                "ContentType": "Document",
                "Created": "2018-10-25T04:20:05Z",
                "AuthorLookupId": "6",
                "EditorLookupId": "6",
                "_CheckinComment": "",
                "LinkFilenameNoMenu": "CenterText.js",
                "LinkFilename": "CenterText.js",
                "DocIcon": "js",
                "FileSizeDisplay": "1209",
                "ItemChildCount": "0",
                "FolderChildCount": "0",
                "_ComplianceFlags": "",
                "_ComplianceTag": "",
                "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime": "",
                "_ComplianceTagUserId": "",
                "_CommentCount": "",
                "_LikeCount": "",
                "Edit": "0",
                "_UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "ParentVersionStringLookupId": "4",
                "ParentLeafNameLookupId": "4"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```